# Rating A Industry Standard Java Developer

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to rate a Java Developer based on industry standard. For example:

Level 1
Level 2
Level 3

So in each of these levels, there are certain things that a Java Developer must meet.

What I actually mean is there some sort of system or something that we can rate a Java Developer based on industry standard? So a Java Developer meets certain things to be a Level 3.

Comment: In which editio? In which field? With experience in what APIs & frameworks?

Answer (score 4):

> is there some sort of system or something that we can rate a Java Developer based on industry standard?

Not really. The Java eco-system is so complex that you can take a developer of twenty years experience and in a different project will have almost none of the skills required.

Java development experience, skills and interests are very diverse.  Even common terms which you might think are specific have very broad meanings.

*Can you write a low latency system?*

If you have low latency development experience this could mean

- You worked on system which supported low latency systems.
- You worked on a system where all the low latency stuff was don't by the core developers.
- You worked on the core low latency code, but it was written by the people before you.
- You designed and coded the core low latency system.

You would think the last answer would be enough except here somes the next question.

How low is low latency? 1s, 100ms, 10ms, 1ms, 100us

If you have worked on a 100ms system but you need a 100 micro-second system (that 1000x difference) its not the same at all.

Ok say we need a 1 ms system and you worked on a 1 ms system, the next question is quality and scale. was 1 ms the average or the 99% tile or 99.99% tile. The way you code such a program is quite different. e.g. lock-free, ultra-low GC, off heap memory, multi-threaded, cache efficient, possibly JNI to kernel bypass network devices.

If it took 1 ms to do not very much or it took 1 ms get data from the network to use the GPU and write to disk as well, send a response to an exchange, that's different again.

When simple question on a specialist area has complex answers its very hard to come up with standard levels across all of Java.

---

A different question is; what do recruiters used when grading individuals.  The most common metric is number of years of experience in XXXX.  Its crude and simple but its a good first step.

Comment: Thanks, actaully that's what I mean. What do recruiters used to grade individuals? It is actually from a Developer's perspective. Any idea where I can find this information?

Comment: This answer made sense to the question!

Comment: The best way to find out what recruiters look for in your area is to use a job search engine.  You can look for the most common keywords asked for, and want range of salary they offer.   I used jobserve.co.uk to find what recruiter looked for. I haven't done for  a few years because talking to recruiters about what the market is looking for is a better indication.

Comment: @thujeevan Hopefully informative as well. ;)

Comment: Actaully, I work in a software company as a Java Developer. I have been asked to find out some information to help them decide what level I am on? This is required for increase in salary and promotion. I need to define what level 1, level 2, level 3 and above is. I am not sure what to do?

Comment: In that case, I would start with what is offered out there for similar positions like yours. Basically, if you leave you will have to do that anyway. Its the extra skills you have which will make the difference.